# Inspect all items on ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

If the first prematchGame has 1 and 2 value ,after that add header , but in this case i have some issue ,,,first element hasn't 1 and 2 value , but 3th and 4th has it . (see on image)

How can i check , that if 1 element has 1 and 2 value in ng-repeat then add in header .

My code 
(and sorry for bad english)

```
 <ul>
   <li ng-show="groupGames[0].firstMarket.events.P1" title="1">1</li>
   <li ng-show="groupGames[0].firstMarket.events.P2" title="2">2</li>
 <ul>

 <div ng-repeat="prematchGame in groupGames track by prematchGame.id"> 
   ...
 </div>
```

[image]

Comment: are you willing to add all elements of the groupGames that contails value of 1 and 2 to the header?

Comment: @Pengyy I want to check , if just 1 prematchGame groupGames has 1 and 2 value , then add header

Comment: so there will be two or more prematchGame that contains value of 1 and 2? you want the first one of that to be shown to the header?

Comment: @Pengyy Hmm exactly  no . 
For example i have 5 prematchGame in groupGames
if one of them has events.P1 and .events.P2 ,then put 1 and 2 in header

Comment: thanks for explaining so much, check whether the answer helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

define a function to filter for the target item.

```
$scope.hasItemWithProperty = function (key) {
    return $scope.groupGames.some(prematchGame => {
        return prematchGame.firstMarket.events.hasOwnProperty(key);
    });
}
```

use the function in the template like this

```
<ul>
  <li ng-show="hasItemWithProperty('P1')" title="1">1</li>
  <li ng-show="hasItemWithProperty('P2')" title="2">2</li>
<ul>
```

this is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/tsxAOCJsXXrAvZQgx2LV?p=preview) of the above.

Comment: why after this in console i have this problem ... Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined ??

Comment: can you tell the type of groupGames? isn't it an array? also check whether you have data in groupGames.

Comment: groupgames is object

Comment: according to the error infomation, $scope.groupGames is undefined.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
at ChildScope.$scope.hasItemWithValueOf2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136911/discussion-between-pengyy-and-aro-tonoyan).